# Integer type conversion and get hash code in C#

Tags: c#

In .Net:

```
Int16 d1 = n;
Int32 d2 = (Int32)d1;
```

Does
`d1.GetHashCode()` equal `d2.GetHashCode()`
for any 16 bit integer `n`?

And does the same relationship hold with `Int32` and `Int64`, and with `UInt16` to `Int32`?  Would this same relationship hold for all integer conversions?

Comment: Did you at least try it yourself?

Comment: Easy to try and very unclear how comparison of hash code for unrelated types could be used in practice... Explanation why would you want to do that could make post at least marginally ok.

Comment: I am working on a set of row,table, column classes which accepts boxed or string representations of primitive types for optimizing reads from the table.  It stores unboxed values by upconverting the entire column based on user demand such as a function like "double Column.GetDouble(int rowIndex)"  Im sure this has been done before, but i can't find what i need.GetHashCode for a cell in the table must return the worst case upconversion, since the entire column could get converted at any time:  therefore, even if a column currently stores floats, it must return ((decimal)myfloat).getHashCode()

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, which you could have checked yourself with a simple program.

```
float d1 = 0.5f;
double d2 = (double)d1;

Console.WriteLine(d1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(d2.GetHashCode());
```

returns

```
1056964608
1071644672
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping no one would answer, considering OP didn't put in the effort. Oh well...

Comment: If you answering bad question consider at least answering what sample of what is asked - it is about integer values converted to float-> double... (Fails for 1, so easy fix and clearly easy test by OP).

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsofts Source Code Page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)
`GetHashCode` for `float`:

```
public unsafe override int GetHashCode() 
{
    float f = m_value;
    if (f == 0) {
        // Ensure that 0 and -0 have the same hash code
        return 0;
    }
    int v = *(int*)(&f);
    return v;
}
```

and for `double`:

```
public unsafe override int GetHashCode() 
{
    double d = m_value;
    if (d == 0) {
        // Ensure that 0 and -0 have the same hash code
        return 0;
    }
    long value = *(long*)(&d);
    return unchecked((int)value) ^ ((int)(value >> 32));
}
```

as you can see the answer is: No

Besides that a small program could have told you that as well.

Comment: That damn pesky negative zero has bitten me enough to realize why they dont even bother in the .NET framework (of course it is fully supported on the CLR).

Answer (score 1):

From the same source code page as posted by Frank J

I know now the answer is no, and that I should cast before getting the hashcode for my situation

UInt16.GetHashCode:

```
internal ushort m_value;
// Returns a HashCode for the UInt16
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (int)m_value;
}
```

Int16.GetHashCode:

```
internal short m_value;
// Returns a HashCode for the Int16
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int)((ushort)m_value) | (((int)m_value) << 16));
}
```

UInt32.GetHashCode:

```
internal uint m_value;
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int) m_value);
}
```

Int32.GetHashCode:

```
internal int m_value;
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return m_value;
}
```

Int64.GetHashCode:

```
internal long m_value;
// The value of the lower 32 bits XORed with the uppper 32 bits.
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return (unchecked((int)((long)m_value)) ^ (int)(m_value >> 32));
}
```

UInt64.GetHashCode

```
internal ulong m_value;
// The value of the lower 32 bits XORed with the uppper 32 bits.
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ((int)m_value) ^ (int)(m_value >> 32);
}
```